# how to display entered students info completely at last in given java program

Tags: java

without using array.. if number of students = 2 and i'm giving two students information using getdata() and finally i want to display student 1 and student 2 informations. but here only it displays last entered student information i.e student 2 information... can you solve this...!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StudInfo
{
int regno;
String name,course;
int eng,tam,mat,tot;
double avg;
//*
void getdata()
{
Scanner ip=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("\n\n Enter Roll No.\t:\t");
regno=ip.nextInt();
System.out.print("\n Enter Name   \t:\t");
name=ip.next();
System.out.println();
System.out.print(" Enter Marks [English, Tamil and Maths Marks out of 100] : ");
eng=ip.nextInt();
tam=ip.nextInt();
mat=ip.nextInt();
}
//*
void display()
{
tot=eng+tam+mat;
avg=tot/3;
System.out.println("\n"+"\n Roll No.\t:\t"+regno+
    "\n Name   \t:\t"+name+
    "\n English\t:\t"+eng+
    "\n Tamil   \t:\t"+tam+
    "\n Maths   \t:\t"+mat+
    "\n Total   \t:\t"+tot+
    "\n Average\t:\t"+avg);


System.out.print(" Grade   \t:\t");
if((eng>=50)&&(tam>=50)&&(mat>=50))
{
if(avg>=91) System.out.print("O");
else if(avg>=81) System.out.print("A");
else if(avg>=71) System.out.print("B");
else if (avg>=61) System.out.print("C");
else if(avg>=51) System.out.print("D");
else System.out.print("Fail");
}
else System.out.print("Fail");
System.out.println();
}
//*
public static void main(String arg[])
{
StudInfo s=new StudInfo();
int maxs,nos;
Scanner ip1=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("\nEnter No. of Students : "); 
nos=ip1.nextInt();
for(maxs=1;maxs<=nos;maxs++) 
{
System.out.println("\nWelcome to Student database");
System.out.print("\n Enter Student [ "+maxs+" ] details");
s.getdata();
}
s.display();
}
}
```

i want to display entered number of students info.. but here displaying last entered student info.. can you solve this...

Comment: Use ArrayList at getData() method.

Comment: does writing complete words cost you?

Comment: if number of students = 2 and i'm giving two students information using getdata() and finally i want to display student 1 and student 2 informations. but here only it displays last entered student information i.e student 2 information... Thank You....

Comment: without using array.. if number of students = 2 and i'm giving two students information using getdata() and finally i want to display student 1 and student 2 informations. but here only it displays last entered student information i.e student 2 information... Thank You....

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int maxs, nos;
    Scanner ip1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\nEnter No. of Students : ");
    nos = ip1.nextInt();
    StudInfo[] studInfos = new StudInfo[nos];
    for (maxs = 0; maxs < nos; maxs++) {
        System.out.println("\nWelcome to Student database");
        System.out.print("\n Enter Student [ " + (maxs + 1) + " ] details");
        studInfos[maxs] = new StudInfo();
        studInfos[maxs].getdata();
    }
    for (StudInfo s : studInfos) {
        s.display();
    }
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: without using arrays, you would have to call s.display() right after s.getdData() which you display the information right after you finish entering on each iteration. if you want to give all the info first and display all of them later, then i'm pretty sure you would need to use arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Change your main method with below code

```
public static void main(String arg[])
{
    List<StudInfo> students = new ArrayList<StudInfo>();
    int maxs,nos;
    Scanner ip1=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("\nEnter No. of Students : "); 
    nos=ip1.nextInt();
    for(maxs=1;maxs<=nos;maxs++) 
    {
        System.out.println("\nWelcome to Student database");
        System.out.print("\n Enter Student [ "+maxs+" ] details");
        StudInfo s = new StudInfo();
        s.getdata();
        students.add(s);
    }
    for (StudInfo s : students) {
        s.display();
    }
}
```

This will print all the student list.

In your code you are just storing the last student details in the `s` **reference**.
This will store all the `StudInfo` details in the `students` **list**